# Shader has strange input values

Tags: directx, shader, directx-11, sharpdx

my current issue is the following: I try to create a SpriteBatch with integrated Primtive-Rendering (Sprite and PrimtiveBatch in one).

Currently Visual Studio 11's Debugger shows that there is a line rendered. The IA-Stage is correct, so the VertexShader-Stage is. But i don´t get any output.

I run over it with the debugger and found out, that the shader has abnormal huge values.

I´m passing two vertices: 20,20 (Position) and 80, 80 (Position) both colored black.
The ConstantBuffer has three matrices: World (for manual object transformation), View and Projection.

In code, they´re all correct:
M11 = 0.00215749722, and so on.
In the shader, it looks like this:

Position = x = 200000.000000000, y = 200000.000000000, z = 0.000000000, w = 0.000000000
(#1 vertex's position)

```
    Projection[0] = x = 22.000000000, y = 0.000000000, z = 0.000000000, w = 0.000000000
    Projection[1]   x = 0.000000000, y = -45.000000000, z = 0.000000000, w = 0.000000000
    Projection[2]   x = 0.000000000, y = 0.000000000, z = 10000.000000000, w = 0.00000 0000
    Projection[3]   x = 0.000000000, y = 0.000000000, z = 0.000000000, w = 10000.000000000
```

And finally the output result (position) is 0 for XYZW.
Before it was 413,-918 or something like that. I don´t know why, but now the result is always 0...

This is very strange, and i´m totaly stuck :-/

Thanks
R

Comment: Your projection matrix doesn't look right, in particular row 3's w should be 1, row 2's z should be a small number. Are you setting it manually?

Comment: I´m using the SharpDX Matrix-class. So no ;)